# cmake formatted string output

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I'm using cmake (3.1) and I'm trying to convert a version string that's been passed to a find_package() function into a specially formatted version string that another find_package() function makes use of. In particular, I'm trying to convert something that looks like

```
"1.57.0"
```

into something that looks like

```
"105700"
```

(If you haven't guessed yet, this is for FindBoost.cmake which needs Boost_VERSION in the form "105700").

I'm just realizing that I have no idea how to do this in cmake; there doesn't seem to be a command/macro expansion/function to do formatted output with fixed field widths and leading zeros? Like `%d%03d%02d` in printf. Or is there?

Update: I bungled the version number. Updated to reflect this.

Update2: It looks like the version logic in FindBoost.cmake is failing for me for a more subtle reason than what I've stated here.

As @Torbjörn and @Antonio below has pointed out, `Boost_VERSION` is an OUTPUT variable to FindBoost.cmake, not the automatically constructed variable that serves as input. Rather, `find_package(Boost 1.57.0)` will automatically create variables called `Boost_FIND_VERSION`, `Boost_FIND_VERSION_MAJOR`, `Boost_FIND_VERSION_MINOR`, `Boost_FIND_VERSION_PATCH`, and `Boost_FIND_VERSION_TWEAK`. FindBoost.cmake then constructs `Boost_VERSION` from these itself, and compares them against a version number of the form `105700` similar to what appears in `version.hpp` in the Boost source. The source of my confusion here is that when I invoked `find_package(Boost 1.57.0)`, it seems FindBoost.cmake had a problem constructing `Boost_VERSION` and fell through its version check. Then when I tried `find_package(Boost 105700)`, it no longer seems to fail the check. Perhaps there's logic to detect a `version.hpp`-style version (ie is the whole version in `Boost_FIND_VERSION_MAJOR`?) Or perhaps `find_package(Boost 105700)` broke something else.

Anyways, it's instructive to know that cmake has no facility for formatted string output yet.

Comment: Counter question: Why do you need to set `Boost_VERSION` manually? It's one of the variables `FindBoost` will define for you when running `find_package(Boost 1.57.0)`.

Comment: What you say doesn't correspond with the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/module/FindBoost.html). Boost_VERSION *is set* by `find_package(Boost)` or `find_package(Boost 1.57.0)`. Without knowing the complete story, the only conversion that seems to make sense here is  *from* 015700 *to* 1.57.0 (Which is anyway probably not so difficult as you can use instead `Boost_MAJOR_VERSION`, `Boost_MINOR_VERSION`, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pessimistic answer**
No, there is no such functionality for producing formatted output in CMake.

**Optimisitic Answer**
Roll your own.

I don't know the exact logic for padding the version string with leading and trailing dots, however, the [`string` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/command/string.html) offers all the subcommands you probably will need (plus the one or the other `if` block).
E.g., use `REPLACE` to get rid of the dots:

```
string(REPLACE "." "" "${version}" version_wo_dots)
```

Comment: An even easier approach is string(REPLACE "." ";" %{version} version_list). But I really wanted to know whether cmake has formatted string output, which I guess it doesn't. I'm going to mark this as the answer